# Volume Scatter doesn't seem to change density

Tags: shaders, volumetrics

[image][image]I've been staring at this for a while now, testing densities and changing settings on. Feeling like the answer is right in front of me.

3.0.1 - Cycles

Comment: You’ve tried fractional densities?

Comment: Can you add rendered examples for densities 0.1, 0.5, 1, 5, 10, 50, 100? Please use a color besides that of the background, such as yellow If BG is default.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize the photo was never uploaded. I've tried all those densities, and nothing has changed. Changing the color also doesn't change anything. It's as if the material isn't applied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two material slots for this object, one of which contains the Volumetric material, but the other of which (the first one) is empty. It’s clear from the viewport that the Volumetric material is not in use, so I suspect that the empty material slot has all the faces of the mesh assigned to it, and was probably the default slot. An empty material slot defaults to a solid white material.

- Remove the empty material slot to make all faces reassign to the remaining one, or;
- Remove the second material slot, and load the volumetric material into
  the remaining one.